# ES6 Modules - 3 ways of importing files

Tags: javascript, import, module, export, es6-modules

Hello guys i have a little question about importing files into a single .js file.

Which way is better (best practice), what's the scenario that is used for:

1. `import './file;'`
2. `import { something } from './file'`
3. `import * as evertything from './file'`

Because i see that `2` and `3` are the same thing but different syntax(maybe `Syntactic Sugar`).

Comment: There is no good practice, all of them do different things. In the first case, the whole file is **loaded** (NOT imported). In the second case, only `exports.something` is imported. In the third case, everything is imported under `evertything`, like if that was a namespace, so accessing `something` would be `evertything.something`.

Answer (score 16):

All three do different things.

> `import './file;'`

That loads the file, and does not import anything. This is useful if you want to initialize that module (or add some external dependency, e.g. a css file if you use Webpack).

> `import { something } from './file'`

That just imports `something` from the file, therefore a bundler could optimize all other dependencies away. I'd always try to go with that instead of

> `import * as evertything from './file'`

That imports *everything* from that module under a namespace, and therefore makes treeshaking more difficult (the bundler cannot optimize it well). I'd only use that if you need everything from that dependency, or if that dependency is loaded externally nevertheless (e.g. `import * as React from "react"`).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following MDN documentation will make you clear about those things:

[import - JavaScript|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

As far as I know, 1st method is used when you have only one default export. 2nd is used when you have multiple default exports but you don't want all of them to load and want only few of them. 3rd is the case when you want everything under a single object (which can be used similar to namespace in other programming languages).